# jQuery how to compare two CSS values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hello I want to do the following:

```
if ($(this).height() == $(this).css('max-height')) {}
```

Problem is that outputs:

```
console.log( $(this).height() + '  '  + $(this).css('max-height'))
```

as:

```
140  140px
```

Any ideas on how to normalize this without hacking or adding crazy amounts of code?

Comment: Except from getting the substring and parse it as an int? No clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/height/

> The difference between .css('height') and .height() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .height() method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

So, this should work:

`if ($(this).css('height') == $(this).css('max-height')) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Easy as hell:

```
if(($(this).height() + "px") == etc…
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($(this).height() + 'px') == $(this).css('max-height')) {}
```

Note that `.height()` gets the computed height, not a CSS value.

Answer (score -1):

This worked better for me:

```
if ($(this).height() == parseInt($(this).css('max-height'))) {}
```